# Proof of why Lagrangian Multipliers work

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and we wish to optimize $f(\vec{x})$ subject to k constraints: $g_i(\vec{x}) = c_i \quad \forall i \in \{1,...,k\}$

Now it is clear that at a local max/min, say $\vec{x}^*,  \nabla f(\vec{x}^*)$ is orthogonal to the any curve $r(x)$ that satisfies the $g_i$ constraints (i.e. $\nabla f(\vec{x}^*) \cdot r^{'}(\vec{x}^*) = 0) \quad\quad \textbf{(1)}$.

Therefore, it is also clear to me that if $\nabla f(\vec{x}^*) = \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i \nabla g_i(\vec{x}^*)$ then $\textbf{(1)}$ will hold (since each of the $\nabla g_i(\vec{x}^*)$ are orthogonal to the curve themselves.  However, I am confused as to why the converse is true.

Why is it that if $\nabla f(\vec{x}^*) \cdot r^{'}(\vec{x}^*) = 0, \nabla f(\vec{x}^*)$ MUST be in the span of the gradients of the $g_i$?

Comment: What do you mean by curve $ r (x) $ ?

Comment: "Curve" is probably the wrong word to use since I just mean something analogous to a space curve in 3D or a plane curve in 2D (as in $r(\vec{x}(t))$ is any parameterization that satisfies $g_i(r(\vec{x}(t))) = c_i$)

Comment: This is just duality, if $A,B$ are (closed) subspaces then $A \subset B$ **iff** $B^\bot \subset A^\bot$. (That is, if whenever $r$ is in the orthogonal complement of the $\nabla g_i(x)$, we have $r$ in the orthogonal complement of $\nabla f(x)$, then $\nabla f(x)$ is in the span of the constraint gradients.)

Comment: This is the key to your answer https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem